# How many ways we can monitor AEM 6.x user activities when they are working on content as well as assets

Tags: java, aem, osgi-bundle, sling, crx

How many ways we can monitor Aem user activities when they are working on content as well as assets( edit, delete, move, update)

I see that there is 2 ways we can monitor (please correct me on this)
1.  from crx/de in var/audit
2. from enabling audit.log.

Is there any other way we can monitor user activities and how?

Comment: Are you after monitoring or auditing?